# How to remove double slash // in url on apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

i'm trying to remove the double slash in my url with a rewrite rule but it doen't work.

i already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)/+(.*) https://www.example.com/$1$3 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^//(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
```

I created a file test.php my root directory with a dump of $_SERVER inside;
Whenever i call example.com/test.php ou example.com////test.php it always display my file but the $_SERVER['query'] is still containing the ////
How can i redirect it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match with `%{THE_REQUEST}` The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html like the flowing :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,}((?!%20HTTP/1.1\b)\b\w+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Or this :

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s//+(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

So, the code above will remove any additional leading slash.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .